# Where can I download Xcode 10 from as I am facing some problems with Xcode 11?

Tags: xcode

I need to download XCode 10 as I am facing differences between the version I have now which  is XCode 11.4 and the course I am attending now which uses XCode 10 techniques.

So where can I download it from?

Comment: You can download earlier versions of XCode from developer.apple.com, but understand, you'll need to be running the required version (older) of macOS and your Mac may not support it.  But *Techniques?*  programming techniques don't change from version to version.

Answer (score 1):

You can download it from Apple's developer site here:

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Just search for "xcode 10" and you'll be able to download any version of Xcode 10.

Another option would be this third party site that has a nice overview of all the release versions:

https://xcodereleases.com

The download links still go directly to Apple's site.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=xcode, and search for "Xcode 10" and choose an option from the list. 
You will have to sign in with an Apple ID

Comment: the Xcode 10.0 download link is here https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/signin?appIdKey=891bd3417a7776362562d2197f89480a8547b108fd934911bcbea0110d07f757&path=%2Fservices-account%2Fdownload%3Fpath%3D%2FDeveloper_Tools%2FXcode_11%2FXcode_11.xip&rv=1